# Can I change old router into bridge mode and connect new router to it to gain more control over my network

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

Since I want to build small server from old PC, I want to make it accessible from anywhere. My current router is rented from ISP and they blocked any access to admin panel. I can only change some basic things like Wi-Fi SSID and password through ISP own site.

However I do have option to change router mode from router to bridge. So, when I buy a new router and change the old one into bridge will I be able to do more configuration, like forwarding ports, IP management, etc.? Old router is Ubee EVW32C.

FWIW, I'm not behind CGNAT.

Comment: Are you behind a CGNAT?

Comment: I don't have CGNAT

Comment: If bridge mode = DMZ then yes, you'll be able to set port forwarding rules and whatnot with the new router.

Comment: I checked ISP page and they say that if you call them they can turn the "open" mode for me. Then they open admin panel but they set up CGNAT address and merge 2.4G and 5G into one network. Should I do this instead?

Comment: why bother merging the wifi instead? This is as relevant to your problem as making a toasted cheese sandwich.  Ask your internet provider if there are other brands of router that can be used

Comment: @Jgrtowy - I asked if you were behind a CGNAT, and you indicated you were not behind one, but in your very next comment you indicated you were behind one.  So which is it, in either case, that relevant information should added to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm currently not behind one.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Okay, I'll agree that the wifi merge wasn't a important information. I tried to call them about router swap but nobody responded. I'll try to call them again tomorrow.

Comment: Based on everything I know, the answer is 100% yes. If you configure your ISP provided router into “bridge” mode, then the router you connect to it will be able to handle everything you are attempting to do. Yes, your externally facing IP address will still be assigned by the ISP, but past that? You will be free from all of the router restrictions the ISP router has. That is why many people get their own routers.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thank you so much for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes you can!

#### The main reason many users set up their ISP provided router/modems into “bridge” mode is for the exact reasons you explain.

Based on everything I know, the answer is 100% yes. If you configure your ISP provided router into “bridge” mode, then the router you connect to it will be able to handle everything you are attempting to do.

Knowing that, yes, your externally facing IP address will still be assigned by the ISP, but past that? You will be free from all of the router restrictions the ISP router has. That is why many people get their own routers and set their ISP provided combo routers/modems to “bridge” mode.

Answer (score -1):

You wont likely be able to do more configuration on the router - if anything it will reduce what you can do.

What it should allow you to do is put a second (ethernet) router you control behind it - where you may be able to get full control of everything - down to the WAN IP. That said, you should discuss this with your ISP first - as how you configure it will depend on your ISP configuration and the technology used to deliver the Internet.

Comment: Why did you type “the” as “tje” and “that” with “tjat?” Very specific typo. Also, why do you believe Bridge mode to a router, _won’t_ allow port forwarding? Seems to me that is what everyone who has a bridge-mode modem setup like this wants?